# Babel error methods running with jest in React

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, ts-jest

Hi i'm working with jest but idk what happens and now when i try to run npm run test i have this error, i don't know if i need to run another command but was working:

```
Class private methods are not enabled. Please add `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods` to your configuration.
      71 |       : this.#createParallelTestRun(tests, watcher);
      72 |   }
    > 73 |   async #createInBandTestRun(tests, watcher) {
         |   ^
      74 |     process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID = '1';
      75 |     const mutex = (0, _pLimit().default)(1);
      76 |     return tests.reduce(
```

this is my babel.config.js

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: true babel: false -->

  
    module.exports = {
        presets: [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          '@babel/preset-react',
          '@babel/preset-flow',
        ],
        plugins: [
          'babel-plugin-styled-components',
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        ]
      }
```

and this is my jest.config.js:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  // on node 14.x coverage provider v8 offers good speed and more or less good report
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!<rootDir>/out/**',
    '!<rootDir>/.next/**',
    '!<rootDir>/*.config.js',
    '!<rootDir>/coverage/**',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle CSS imports (with CSS modules)
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
 
    // Handle CSS imports (without CSS modules)
    '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
 
    // Handle image imports
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets
    '^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$/i': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
 
    // Handle module aliases
    '^@/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
  },
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel'] }],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg)$',
  ],
}
```

Maybe i'm ignoring somethine or i runned some worth command.
If someone had some similar issue, please let me know